# Numbers: How to escape the "+" character for a phone number

Tags: macos, numbers

I am working on a document in Numbers where I have to write a phone number starting with a **plus character +**, like `+33553379412`, but as soon as I press enter, the plus is going away. Is there any way to show it?

Thank you

Comment: You should set the format of the cell to be text instead of number or auto.

Comment: @Dev no. Phone numbers are text. They are never numbers. How are they numbers if they have preceding 0s? How do you add two phone numbers together? They are not numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by adding the <kbd>'</kbd> character (i.e. the single quote) before entering the `+33553379412`.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` character can be represented as `00` for phone numbers, you could then also replace `+33553379412` with `0033553379412`.